# What will be the output voltage if I supply 1.5V to a 3V to 32V XL6009E1 voltage booster?

Tags: voltage

Basically I need to convert 1.5V DC to 12V DC. If the module mentioned above fails to do the job,then what should I use instead. Is there any way that I can add two voltage sources in series and  then use the resultant 3V DC power to convert it into 12V?

Comment: If your voltage source is a battery, then the obvious is to place two batteries in series to get the voltage. And no, if you have a DC-DC module that requires 3 V input (or more?) then 1.5 V won't cut it. Where is the existing 1.5 VDC coming from?

Comment: There are boost converter chips that are specifically designed for that sort of job.  I don't know if anyone markets a module to do it, but if you're stuck at the module level then you're pretty much stuck with going shopping for one.

Comment: @Rahul - Tell us more about your 12V load. How much current will it be draining?

Comment: The voltage source is a TEG module that converts heat energy to electrical energy. It supplies 1.5V to 1.8V DC current. I haven't yet received data on the current it supplies. I'll mention it when I receive the data.

Comment: It is not going to give you 12V.  Check the data sheet but if that says it needs 3V then it does.  May do nothing or may boost to a voltage <12V depending on the design.

Comment: This project is very unlikely to work at all

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet for the XL6009E1](https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300) says it operates on 5V to 32V.

1.5V is outside of its operating range.  You can't count on it doing anything useful on that voltage.

If you try it and it works, then you still shouldn't do it.  There is no guarantee that an IC from a different batch will be as tolerant of the low voltage.

---

You would do better to find an IC designed for the voltage you need.

Something like the [LM2621 from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/product/LM2621) or any of the many boost regulators you can find if you search for 1.5V to 12V boost converters.

Comment: Also, if you are using an LM2621 your supply must not drop much in voltage when the regulator pulses up to 2.85A, so a Li-Ion cell is recommended.

Comment: Is it possible to make the voltage booster using a LM317T?

Comment: No.  [The LM317 is a linear regulator.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)  Its output voltage must **always** be **lower** than its input voltage.